# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning trying to import json Swagger to insomnia

Tags: npm, swagger, insomnia

I'm trying to import a Json file from Swagger to insomnia. To do that I use this project from NPM (I'm not familiar with NPM):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/insomnia-importers

I have npm v6.5.0 and node v11.9.0 installed.

I ran this command: `insomnia-import /path/to/swagger-export.json

insomnia-export.json:

```
 (node:38053) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot
 convert undefined or null to object
     at Function.keys (<anonymous>)
     at object (/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v11.9.0/lib/node_modules/insomnia-importers/src/importers/swagger2.js:300:14)
     at generateParameterExample (/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v11.9.0/lib/node_modules/insomnia-importers/src/importers/swagger2.js:332:12)
     at Object.keys.forEach.propertyName (/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v11.9.0/lib/node_modules/insomnia-importers/src/importers/swagger2.js:301:33)
     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
     at object (/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v11.9.0/lib/node_modules/insomnia-importers/src/importers/swagger2.js:300:31)
     at generateParameterExample (/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v11.9.0/lib/node_modules/insomnia-importers/src/importers/swagger2.js:332:12)
     at prepareBody (/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v11.9.0/lib/node_modules/insomnia-importers/src/importers/swagger2.js:242:37)
     at importRequest (/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v11.9.0/lib/node_modules/insomnia-importers/src/importers/swagger2.js:173:11)
     at tags.forEach (/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v11.9.0/lib/node_modules/insomnia-importers/src/importers/swagger2.js:129:21)
 (node:38053) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
 rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async
 function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was
 not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1) (node:38053) [DEP0018]
 DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In
 the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
 Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: Can you post your swagger-export.json so that others can reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 10):

Insomnia maintainer here.

Insomnia uses the insomnia-import package internally so you don't have to. You can import your Swagger file directly into Insomnia and it will import it.

Comment: Is it possible to export insomnia json in a way swagger can read it?

Comment: Would it be possible to add a description how this can be done/ link to it?

Comment: https://docs.insomnia.rest/insomnia/import-export-data#import-data   note that if the interface is password protected, you might have to save the .json file and provide it instead of just using the url directly...